# Merge options when reviewing low quality posts

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

When reviewing low quality posts, two of the options are remarkably similar, and could be merged. I see a lot of reviewers get confused about which of these two is most applicable.

- **This is an "I'm having this problem, too" comment**   This does not really answer the question. *If you have a different question, you
  can ask it by clicking Ask Question*. You can also add a bounty to
  draw more attention to this question.

and

- **This is a different question posted as an answer**
  *If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button*. Include a link to this question if it helps provide
  context

I would suggest these two options are merged into one:

- **This is a question posted as an answer**
  This does not really answer the question. If you have the same question you can draw more
  attention to the question by adding a bounty. If you have a new
  question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include
  a link to this question if it helps provide context

Answer (score 4):

These options don't do anything different, they simply ensure that a more understandable message is posted to a user when they do something wrong.  Having a message tailored more to the specific situation decreases the odds that they won't understand it.

If someone posts an answer saying, "I'm having this problem too", that's *not* asking a separate unrelated question.  Telling them that it is will either confuse them, or cause them to try to refute your deletion reason, and it certainly won't make them as likely to fix the behavior.  Likewise, telling someone that asked an entirely unrelated question as an answer that they shouldn't post, "I'm having this problem too" answers has the same problems.

Having two different categories doesn't really hurt anything with respect to actually deleting the post either.  It's not like it needs to collect 6 recommend delete votes in one category, just 6 in general.

Comment: I mostly agree with all that you said. But the current text for "I'm having this problem too" includes 'if you have a different question..' So perhaps that sentence needs removing?  None of this is a huge problem, but I do see quite a few answers which end up with both of the comments above against it, which can't be helping the poster, and defeats the point of having two separate options.

Comment: @PaulG I think that the text is fine.  That the text is somewhat similar doesn't mean that there aren't differences, or that they aren't relevant.  If people are choosing the improper reason when reviewing then *that* is the problem to address.  There aren't going to be many post to which both reasons apply to.  Asking a new question simply *isn't* stating that you have the same problem, and stating the same problem *doesn't* mean you're asking a question in an answer.